# How to send information to all clients, but not to the sender?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I have this server I am working on and so far I have fixed so whenever someone writes it will send it to all clients that have been included in a list. How can I make it so it doesn't send the message to the client who is sending the information? I've been trying to figure it out but I am a bit lost on this one. Here is the code:

```
import socket
import threading
from _thread import *
from threading import Thread

clients = {}

def message(c):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print("Recieved: " + str(data))
        if not data:
            print("Client Disconnected.")
            break

        # skicka meddelanden till client
        for client in clients.values():
            try:
                client.sendall(data.encode("utf-8"))
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                print("[!] Connection aborted ")
            except ConnectionResetError:
                print("[!] Connection reset error ")

def listener():
    host = "192.168.1.77"
    port = 22050
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("\nServer has started.\n\n" + "Host: " + host + "\nPort: " + str(port))
    print("______________________________________________________________________\n")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print(str(addr) + " has connected.")
        clients[c.fileno()] = c
        threading.Thread(target=message, args=(c,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a simple `if` statement after the `for` loop to check if the client in the iteration is equal to the current client in the thread. If it is, skip it:

```
    # skicka meddelanden till client
    for client in clients.values():
        try:
            if client == c: # skip the current client
                continue
            client.sendall(data.encode("utf-8"))
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            print("[!] Connection aborted ")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("[!] Connection reset error ")
```